# Prove that if G is a simple graph, $\chi \geq \frac{|V|^2}{|V|^2-2|E|}$

Tags: inequality, graph-theory, coloring

For a simple graph $G=(V,E)$, I have to prove the following bound on the chromatic number of $G$: 
$$\chi \geq \frac{|V|^2}{|V|^2-2|E|}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tough question.

The result was proved by Myers and Liu in [this paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/net.3230010306/abstract) by induction.

Comment: Seems like they were a few decades late to the game.

Answer (score 5):

Let $G(V,E)$ be a simple graph on the finite vertex set $V$ with the edge set $E$.  Write $v:=|V|$, $e:=|E|$, and $k:=\left\lceil\frac{v^2}{v^2-2e}\right\rceil$.  Then, $k-1<\frac{v^2}{v^2-2e}$, or $$\left(\frac{k-2}{k-1}\right)\frac{v^2}{2}<e\,.$$  By [Turán's Graph Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem) (see also [here](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Aigner808-816.pdf)), $G$ has a $k$-clique.  That means, the chromatic number of $G$ is at least $k$.  In other words, $$\chi(G)\geq \omega(G)\geq \left\lceil\frac{v^2}{v^2-2e}\right\rceil\,.$$  Notice also that this bound is sharp.  As $\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)\frac{v^2}{2}\geq e$, we can take $G$ to be a subgraph of the [Turán graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n_graph) $T(v,k)$ with $e$ edges so that both the clique number $\omega(G)$ and the chromatic number $\chi(G)$ of $G$ are equal to $k$.

Comment: Nice! Incredible that both bounds (the given bound and Turan's bound) are related!