# Upper bound relating number of edges of a graph to it's chromatic number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So I am curious if there is an upper bound relating number of edges of a graph to it's chromatic number. More specifically,

Given a graph $G$ where $\chi(G) = k$, then can we deduce an upper bound for the number of edges $G$ must possess ? There are posts that deduce the lower bound, ($k $ choose 2 many).

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ denote the number of nodes and $m$ the number of edges.

Given that (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774142/prove-that-if-g-is-a-simple-graph-chi-geq-fracv2v2-2e/1775974#1775974)) : 
$$
k \ge \frac{n^2}{n^2-2m}
$$
You can derive the following upper bound for $m$
$$
m \le \frac{n^2(k-1)}{2k}
$$

Answer (score 2):

[Turán's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem) asserts that the maximum number of edges in an $n$-vertex $K_{k+1}$-free graph is achieved by the [Turán graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n_graph), which happens to be $k$-colorable.  Since all $k$-colorable graphs are $K_{k+1}$-free, the maximum number of edges in an $n$-vertex $k$-colorable graph is also achieved by the [Turán graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n_graph).

Thus, the number of edges is at most $$\left(1 - \frac{1}{k}\right)\frac{n^2}{2}.$$  An exact formula is given on the [Turán graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n_graph) Wikipedia page which is a bit messy.