# Chromatic number on a graph

Tags: graph-theory

> Let  $G$ be any graph with order $p$ and size $q$. Prove that $$χ(G)\ge {p^2 \over p^2-2q}$$

If someone could give me a hint it would be amazing!

Comment: I guess order is number of vertices, so what is size?

Comment: number of edges

Comment: You want to prove $q\leq p^2\cdot\frac{\chi-1}{2\chi}$. Take a graph with $p$ vertices and $\chi$-coloring. What is the most edges it can have if all bipartite subgraphs between different color pairs are complete?

Comment: Wow that is really cool! I had another idea. Is it possible to get this directly, by finding a lower bound on the largest clique in a graph? Then $\chi \geq \textrm{largest clique size}$. My idea was to use an averaging method, but no success yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that if G is a simple graph, $\chi \geq \frac{|V|^2}{|V|^2-2|E|}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774142/prove-that-if-g-is-a-simple-graph-chi-geq-fracv2v2-2e)

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek This sounds interesting. Could you post your comment as an answer (with more details) ? It is different from both answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774142/prove-that-if-g-is-a-simple-graph-chi-geq-fracv2v2-2e/1775974#1775974).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose a graph with $v$ vertices has chromatic number $\chi$, so we have a splitting of the vertex set into independent sets of sizes $v_1,\ldots,v_\chi$. Then the number of edges $e$ is at most
$$e\leq \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq \chi}v_iv_j\leq \frac{\chi-1}{2\chi}(\sum_i v_i)^2=\frac{\chi-1}{2\chi}v^2 $$
where the middle inequality is something that holds for all real numbers as it is just $\sum_{i<j}(v_i-v_j)^2\geq 0$.